# CORS issue posting domain A to domain B

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, axios

I am getting a CORS issue only on axios.

In this html page, I am using a traditional form to post from domain A to domain B.

The form submit works correctly. 
The ajax post request works correctly.
The axios post returns me to a CORS .

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://domainB/post.php' from origin 'http://domain A.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <h2>Registration Form</h2>

    <form action="https://domainB.com/post.php" method="POST">

        Last name:

        <input type="text" name="username"> 

        <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="1" />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("https://domainB.com/post.php",
    {
      username: "Donald Duck",
      city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
    </script>
    <script>

(function() {

axios.post('https://domainB.com/post.php', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });


})();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my post.php

```
<?php
echo 'post working';
var_dump( $_POST);
 $_POST['username'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a configuration with the server. I did not do anything on my side and insisted with hosting company. They were able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is controlled by backend.

Browser prevents your code from accessing the response because the browser can't see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in response.

With CORS a preflight request is made to the server to see if the request is allowed. You will need to have your server respond to requests that have `OPTIONS` as request method by setting the header `Acces-Control-Allow-Origin: *` which will allow requests from any origin. Alternatively, you can allow for just certain origins `Acces-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com.`

Things can still get working by making the request through a Proxy can where a proxy sends appropriate CORS header on behalf of your request.

```js
const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "https://domainB.com/post.php"; 
fetch(proxy + url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(contents => console.log(contents))
  .catch(() => console.log("CORS Error" + url ))
```

Making a request through a proxy will work this way

1. CORS proxy will forward your request to `https://domainB.com/post.php`
2. The return response from `https://domainB.com/post.php` with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.
3. Now your browser can see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers present in the response header.

For more detail explanation you can check out this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/2850383